# Error while using TempData values in DropDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have `<div>` and I want to add some `TempData` values to it. I have accessed that values but facing error on browser's console when try to assign to dropdown.

**code :**

```
@{
     var j = TempData["Contents"]; // int
     var i = TempData["ID"];   // string

      }
    var newSelect = document.createElement('select');
    var selectHTML = "";
    selectHTML = "<option id='"+@i+"'>'"+@j+"'</option>";
    newSelect.innerHTML = selectHTML;
    document.getElementById('surah_selection').appendChild(newSelect);
    alert("out");
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: what is the error? What are the `@` for?...they don't belong in javascript concatention

Comment: @charliefl actually i want to show TempData values using razor syntax. thats y using @. without @ , showing 'i' is not defined..

Comment: what error in console?

Comment: @Grundy "Uncaught ReferenceError: ali is not defined"
[where 'ali' is value of @j ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

razor render this script before it execute in browser, so in your case in runtime you have string

```
selectHTML = "<option id='"+ali+"'>'"+alj+"'</option>";
```

so browser try execute value for this variables, for solve this you need change this line something like this

```
selectHTML = "<option id='@i'>@j</option>";
```